# Effective way to find particular directory name?

Tags: php

I have a script that I've written that I sell to others who want a virtual gift application on Facebook.  As many of the customers who buy this script don't actually have programming knowledge, I try to simplify things as much as is possible for them by gathering as much data as I can without their input (such as using `$_SERVER` vars).

I'm running into a problem when trying to establish a static directory for images, though, that the code can read and always know where that directory is.

For instance, on my 'masterfile.php' which is included on most every page I have this:

```
$app_info['server_url']="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$app_info['callback_url']=$app_info['server_url'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/";
$app_info['image_url']=$app_info['callback_url'].'images/';
```

That gives me all the necessary information I need about where folders are located... unless I'm using a directory inside the parent directory to the entire script (IE: /folder/ajax/).

I'm running into a problem where the 'images' folder needs to always be '/folder/images/' instead of ending up as '/folder/ajax/images/' when working with other directories inside the parent.

I can't just hard code the parent directory name as some customers upload them to directories such as '/folder/folder/folder/folder/script/' - that's why I use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to establish the parent directory.

Is there a way (or a variable) that I can use for this problem?  I just need to ensure that the `$app_info['callback_url']` is always the same, regardless of the current directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how many folders the user has so many ../ will be included in the path for images.

```
$dir = scandir('/testdir');
$dots = '/';

for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($dir)-2;$i++) // -2 not to count . and .. as folders
{
    $dots .= '../';
}

$app_info['server_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$app_info['callback_url'] = $app_info['server_url'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/";
$app_info['image_url'] = $app_info['callback_url'] . "{$dots}images/";
```

Comment: Unfortunately the images folder is inside the parent directory, not just on the server.  I know what you're thinking, but when you sell to customers you have to take into account that they might have their own folders they don't want to adjust.

Comment: Since there is no limit for folders and you can make a lot folders /path/to/folder/one/ you may use /../../../../images/.
Example: $app_info['image_url'] = $app_info['server_url'] . '/../../../../images/';

Comment: Well the problem is I won't know exactly how many folders are between the image directory and the server.  It will vary from customer to customer.

Comment: I've edited my post.Count the user defined folders and then add as many ../ as needed.
If it doesn't work, try to changing the sizeof($dir) with -1, because -2 removes the . and .. folders, but we may need to include the current folder (in the example testdir), so this may count . as the current folder testdir.

Answer (score 3):

I would define a *base dir* constant in a bootstrap type file of your application.

```
define('BASE_DIR', basedir(__FILE__));
```

(if you can guarantee >= PHP 5.3, you can just use `__DIR__`.)

Then simply include files based on this constant...

```
include BASE_DIR . '/something.php';
```

Comment: I've had problems with that before (something to do mostly with customers using free hosts in other countries, especially African or European).  I may just route all AJAX calls through a handling file in the parent directory, that way I always have access to the correct directories.